# How to animate change of grid item size Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a project with React and Material UI.

I need some guidance on how to animate a grid item size change. The item is by default sm={3}, when the user hovers the item, this changes to sm={6}. This is done with even triggers and a state variable. My question is how can I create a transition/animation for this?

I tried adding this to the item css but it didn't work.

```
transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeIn,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.sta
})
```

Comment: please share codesandbox for it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this question is three months old but I had the same problem of animating a grid size change in React and Material UI based on a variable in the state.  I was doing a transition for the main page content to smoothly resize when a sidebar expanded and retracted.  I did it with inline styling on the Grid elements.

My code:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid 
    item xs={this.state.expandMainContent === true ? 1 : 2}
    style={{transition: theme.transitions.create("all", {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp, 
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  })}} >
    <Sidebar />
  </Grid>
  <Grid 
    item xs={this.state.expandMainContent === true ? 11 : 10} 
    style={{transition: theme.transitions.create("all", {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp, 
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
   })}}>
     <MainContent />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I did mine on click whereas your's is on hover but it should still work the same.

Comment: This is great! I was able to use the exact same approach inside `makeStyles`

Answer (score 0):

You should animate both ease in and ease out for transition to work,
try with css

```
.item {
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.item:hover {
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I am using onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. That code wouldn't really work for that